# Cannot connect remotely to VSFTPD running on Amazon Linux EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ftp, vsftpd

I have installed VSFTP and configured it by adding the following lines...

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
pasv_address=<ELASTIC_IP>
```

Then I added the port ranges `1024 - 1048` and `20 - 21`. I then restarted VSFTPD and I can reach it locally from the EC2 instance. However, when I try to access it via my local computer (I am logging in anon for now) it asks me for username and password. I enter `ftp` and `a@b.com` but it just hangs after this is entered.

Am I missing something? Do I need to configure iptables? I tried...

```
-A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1024:1048 -j ACCEPT
```

But I get

```
iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 1 failed
                                                       [FAILED]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the security group for your server's IP look like?

Comment: I will post it in a bit but I added the same ports on the iptables. I couldn't even get the login prompt before that

Answer (score 0):

Weird it appears as though it **does** work, it is just that the ftp command runs differently on Cygwin.

When I ftp from the server itself I see..

```
$ ftp localhost
Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1).
220 Welcome to home security FTP service.
Name (localhost:ec2-user): ftp
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

From Cygwin it looks like

```
$ ftp -d <ip>
---> OPTS UTF8 ON
User (52.21.43.5:(none)): ftp
---> USER ftp
Password: a@b.com

---> PASS a@b.com
<blank line>
```

The blank line through me off, however, hitting `ls+enter` gets the list just as I would expect.